# Shiny - Change "Upload complete" and "... files" text in fileInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

As soon as multiple files (say, 6) are uploaded via fileInput, I receive the text "6 files" next to the button, and "Upload complete" in the progress bar. Also, I suppose some text is provided in progress bar in case of emergency (faulty upload or smth.). UI of the app I am writing is in Russian, so all the labels are to be in Russian. According to documentation, I can set just buttonLabel and placeholder labels in fileInput, nothing about the text I mentioned above. Any ideas how can I change it?

Answer (score 9):

It's not a complete solution, as it doesn't solve the problem you were having with multiple files, but it's possibly a start. This changes the text in the progress bar:

---

You can do this using a custom javascript function stored in a file which you include with `tags$script()`. The javascript file needs to sit in the www folder

```
app.r
www
|__ fileInput_text.js
```

**app.r**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$script(src="fileInput_text.js"),
    fileInput('uploaded', 'Data Upload')
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

Custom javascript function: **fileInput_text.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#uploaded_progress').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){

    var target = $('#uploaded_progress').children()[0];
    if(target.innerHTML === "Upload complete"){
        console.log('Change')
        target.innerHTML = 'YOUR TEXT HERE';      
    }

  });
});
```

This function will look for you fileInput's ID (in this case `uploaded`) And will change it from "Upload complete" to what you set it to:

[image: Shiny App output]

Comment: Thanks. Though the answer is partial, that seems to be a nice path.

Answer (score 2):

Since the answer from [aeongrail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4556652/aeongrail) did not work stable in my case, I used the shiny package functions `addCustomMessageHandler` and `sendCustomMessage` as mentioned [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html).This solution did not require any other package than `shiny`.

I did the following steps:

- Create a variable (character) called `jscode_upload_msg` which contains the js code as text. The code is similar to the answer from [aeongrail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4556652/aeongrail).

```
jscode_upload_msg <- "
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('upload_msg', function(msg) {
  var target = $('#uploaded_progress').children()[0];
  target.innerHTML = msg;
});
"
```

- Added the code via the call: `tags$script(jscode_upload_msg)` in the UI function
- Added in the server part an update call:

```
observe({
  req(input$uploaded)
  session$sendCustomMessage("upload_msg", "YOUR TEXT")
})
```

The advantage from this solution is that you can set the text depending on any variable. In my case I implemented a function which checks the uploaded file. I set the text to `Valid File` or `Invalid File` depending on check success or not.

Answer (score 1):

In Shiny version 1.0.5 message "Upload complete" is hardcoded in the javascript source files.You would need to modify the source files or to add a javascript hack to your application to change the text. Alternatively, you could hide the message with some CSS. It isn't the same as a translation, but it could be good enough in some situations.

1. Create file app.css in the same folder of ui.R and add to it `.progress-bar {color: transparent!important}`
2. Add `includeCSS("app.css")` to the UI, for instance:

   `# Define UI for data upload app ----
   ui <- fluidPage(
     includeCSS("app.css"),
     # The rest of your page...`

It works by making the font color transparent in the progress bar. The text is still there but it's invisible.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited (hacked :)) JS code. Though it works, your variant seems more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

vim /usr/lib64/R/library/shiny/www/shared/shiny.min.js
and search the word "Upload complete" then replace it.
attention the encoding.